# Run powershell script on Azure VM with Azure Fluent API

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, azure-fluent-api

I am trying to run powershell command to install mysql on AzureVM, but I am not able to succeed.

```
var windowsVmAccessExtensionName = "VMAccessAgent";
            var windowsVmAccessExtensionPublisherName = "Microsoft.Compute";
            var windowsVmAccessExtensionTypeName = "VMAccessAgent";
            var windowsVmAccessExtensionVersionName = "2.3";
            var mySqlScriptWindowsInstallCommand = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File installMySQL.ps1";
            var mySQLWindowsInstallScriptFileUris = new List<string>()
        {
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/master/Samples/Asset/installMySQL.ps1"
        };

            //azure.VirtualMachines.RunPowerShellScript(rgName, vmName, mySQLWindowsInstallScriptFileUris, asdf);

            var windowsVM = azure.VirtualMachines.GetByResourceGroup(rgName, vmName);

            windowsVM.Update()
                       .DefineNewExtension(windowsVmAccessExtensionName)
                           .WithPublisher(windowsVmAccessExtensionPublisherName)
                           .WithType(windowsVmAccessExtensionTypeName)
                           .WithVersion(windowsVmAccessExtensionVersionName)
                           .WithPublicSetting("fileUris", mySQLWindowsInstallScriptFileUris)
                           .WithPublicSetting("commandToExecute", mySqlScriptWindowsInstallCommand)
                       .Attach()
                       .Apply();
```

this code even not throwing any error as well, and when I check the VM there is no any mysql or choco installed on VM.

Please suggest or help on  Azure FLuent API to execute command of powershell on Azure VM.

**UPDATE**

Update the below code able to run powershell script.

```
var scriptUris = new List<string>()
        {
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/dotnet-core-sample-templates/master/dotnet-core-music-windows/scripts/configure-music-app.ps1"
        };

        var windowsVM = azure.VirtualMachines.GetByResourceGroup(rgName, vmName);
        windowsVM.Update()
                   .UpdateExtension("CustomScriptExtension")
                    //.WithPublisher(windowsVmAccessExtensionPublisherName)
                    //.WithType(windowsVmAccessExtensionTypeName)
                    //.WithVersion(windowsVmAccessExtensionVersionName)
                       .WithPublicSetting("fileUris", scriptUris)
                       .WithPublicSetting("commandToExecute", "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File configure-music-app.ps1")
                    //.Attach()
                    //.Apply();
                    .Parent()
                    .Apply();
```

But, for some reason might be for long running process I am getting this error :-

> One or more errors occurred. (Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CustomScriptExtension'. Error message: "Finished executing command"
>
> More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot

Comment: Could you please provide your powershell script?

Comment: Besides, could you tell me if you can install mysql with the script manually?

Comment: @JimXu here is the .ps1 : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/master/Samples/Asset/installMySQL.ps1

Manually its working,

Comment: Ok. I will check it

Comment: Could you please ensure if you can install mysql with script? When I use it, you get error.

Comment: Besides, is that you use Azure Windows server VM?

Comment: Yes, its windows 2016-Datacenter 

I have changed the windowsVmAccessExtensionName to "CustomScriptExtension" and then powershell script started executing. but now I am getting this error : "One or more errors occurred. (Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CustomScriptExtension'. Error message: "Finished executing command"

More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "

Comment: According to my understanding, you can install the mysql with the script in the VN by yourself. But you cannot install mysql with the script by CustomScriptExtension. Is that right?

Comment: Jim Xu, yes.

I have updated the azure-fluent api call and  powershell script :- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sw-ms-saurinvala/pipelines-dotnet-core/master/test.ps1

It's partially working, 

It installed Firefox, but not VLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following code to install MySQL with  custom script extension.

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
             var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure()
                         .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                         .Authenticate(credentials)
                         .WithSubscription(SubscriptionId);
            var windowsVmAccessExtensionName = "installmysql";
            var windowsVmAccessExtensionPublisherName = "Microsoft.Compute";
            var windowsVmAccessExtensionTypeName = "CustomScriptExtension";
            var windowsVmAccessExtensionVersionName = "1.9";
            var mySqlScriptWindowsInstallCommand = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File installMySQL.ps1";
            var mySQLWindowsInstallScriptFileUris = new List<string>()
        {
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/master/Samples/Asset/installMySQL.ps1"
        };

            //azure.VirtualMachines.RunPowerShellScript(rgName, vmName, mySQLWindowsInstallScriptFileUris, asdf);

            var windowsVM = azure.VirtualMachines.GetByResourceGroup("testInstance", "test");

            windowsVM.Update()
                       .DefineNewExtension(windowsVmAccessExtensionName)
                           .WithPublisher(windowsVmAccessExtensionPublisherName)
                           .WithType(windowsVmAccessExtensionTypeName)
                           .WithVersion(windowsVmAccessExtensionVersionName)
                           .WithPublicSetting("fileUris", mySQLWindowsInstallScriptFileUris)
                           .WithProtectedSetting("commandToExecute", mySqlScriptWindowsInstallCommand)
                       .Attach()
                       .Apply();
```

[image] 
[image]