# How to run Azure Powershell scripts on an Azure VMs via dot net / C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I'm relatively new to Azure and hope someone can help me.  I have an azure VM on which I have installed Azure Powershell.  I am able to run the following script to move some files from Azure storage onto the VM with no issues:

```
$path = "C:\Users\AdminUser\Desktop\test\"
$ConName = 'my-container'
$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString <my connection string>
$List = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx
$List = $List.name
foreach ( $l in $list ){Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $l -Container $conname -Context $ctx -Destination $path}
```

However, I run into an issue when I try replicate the above using the .NET azure SDK:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent.Models;

var scriptLines = new List<string>();
var scriptParams = new List<RunCommandInputParameter>();

scriptLines.Add(@"$path = 'C:\Users\AdminUser\Desktop\test\'");
scriptLines.Add("$ConName = 'my-container'");
scriptLines.Add("$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString <my connection string>");
scriptLines.Add("$List = Get-AzStorageBlob  -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx");
scriptLines.Add("$List = $List.name");
scriptLines.Add("foreach ( $l in $list ){Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $l -Container $conname -Context $ctx -Destination $path}");

var result = vm.RunPowerShellScript(scriptLines, scriptParams);
```

The following error is always thrown:

```
"New-AzStorageContext : The term 'New-AzStorageContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script \nfile, or operable program...
```

Can anyone help me with this?  It seems the SDK is unable to detect the Azure Powershell installation on the VM, though I have installed it for all users.  I know the script syntax is fine as I can run it from within Powershell on the VM.  Is there another way to run Azure Powershell scripts from within C#?  I would rather not have the script saved on the VM if possible.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT - as a workaround I installed AZCopy and was able to use 'vanilla' powershell (not the Azure variant) to get AZCopy to move the files around that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the strings as literals, you have \ chars in your string data.

```
scriptLines.Add(@"$path = 'C:\Users\AdminUser\Desktop\test\'");
scriptLines.Add(@"$ConName = 'my-container'");
scriptLines.Add(@"$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString <my connection string>");
scriptLines.Add(@"$List = Get-AzStorageBlob  -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx");
scriptLines.Add(@"$List = $List.name");
scriptLines.Add(@"foreach ( $l in $list ){Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $l -Container $conname -Context $ctx -Destination $path}");
```

The @ at the start of the string tells C# to not interpret \ as special character.

Comment: Hi I have updated the code in my question - I am using string literals in my code, i just missed thme in my question.  Unfortunately this didn't help as the error I am getting is a powershell specific error.

Comment: There is a similar question and has an accepted answer for running PowerShell Script on an Azure VM using C# - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59373685/run-powershell-script-on-azure-vm-with-azure-fluent-api